# Batch file not working with start command

Tags: c++, command-line, batch-file

I need to run a batch file from C++ which executes a .exe application, the .exe is a free program called dumpedid which writes monitor's edid to a text file. I've used CreateProcess and it works as long as the batch file doesn't use the start command

```
"DumpEDID.exe" > "edid.txt" // this works
start /wait /d "DumpEDID.exe" > "edid.txt" // this doesn't
```

I want to use the /wait command however so this is a problem. Could this just be an issue with the application itself? My code to run the batch file is below

```
std::ofstream fs;
fs.open(DUMP_EDID_BATCH_FILE_PATH);
fs << "\"" << DUMP_EDID_EXE_PATH << "\" > \"" << DUMP_EDID_TXT_FILE_PATH << "\"";
fs.close();

STARTUPINFOA si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

std::string str = (std::string)"/c " + "\"" + DUMP_EDID_BATCH_FILE_PATH + "\"";
char * cmdLine = new char[str.size() + 1];
strncpy(cmdLine,str.c_str(), str.size());
cmdLine[str.size()] = '\0';

if( !CreateProcessA( "c:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe", 
    cmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) ) 
{
    delete[] cmdLine;
    DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
    g_log.Info(_T("CreateProcess failed - error code %d"), errCode);
    return errCode;
}

delete[] cmdLine;

WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```

Thanks.

EDIT - I just tried running the batch file directly from the command line and I noticed something strange, the contents of the batch file is

start /wait /d "D:...\dumpedid" > "D:...\edid.txt"

but the command that shows up when I run the batch file is

start /wait /d "D:...\dumpedid"  1>"D:...\edid.txt"

Notice the 1 before the > symbol and the extra space before the 1

Comment: Try to use `start "myTitle" /wait /d "DumpEDID.exe" > "edid.txt"` instead

Comment: Hi Jeb,

I tried that and had the same result, it just produces an empty text file. Is it possible that the dumpedid application is just faulty and doesn't handle the start command or something?

Comment: Re your edit: that's normal, and unrelated to your issue. `1>` and `>` are synonymous, the shell is just a bit more explicit about what it's running. Re your question: why aren't you running dumpedid directly from your C++ code?

Comment: In the msdn article for [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says 'To run a batch file, you must start the command interpreter; set lpApplicationName to cmd.exe and set lpCommandLine to the following arguments: /c plus the name of the batch file.' 

Are you suggesting that I am using CreateProcess incorrectly? Or that I shouldn't be using CreateProcess at all and there's a way to run a batch file without the command interpreter?

Comment: You can use ShellExecute instead of CreateProcess, but it won't solve your problem. The problem is in your batch file, see the answer of jeb below. It would be better not using a batch file at all, and do everything in your c++ code. But if your batch file is very long or complicated, I would understand to do it this way. If the batch file does not much more than calling DumpEDID.exe, then you should use CreateProcess to execute DumpEDID.exe. Use STARTUPINFO to redirect output to a file. You can use WaitForSingleObject to wait until the process has stopped.

Comment: To clarify, the reason I was using a batch file was because I needed to redirect the output of the executable and that isn't simple with CreateProcess apparently, so I put the redirection in the batch file instead and just ran that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`start` needs at two points a bit attention.

The title option is the first quoted argument, so if you have a quoted cmd you need also a title option.
`start "myTitle" /start "cmd"`

If you try to redirect the output you need to escape the redirection, as the *normal* redirection will redirect the output of the `start` command not of the started command!

`start "" /wait /d "DumpEDID.exe" ^> "edid.txt"`